# Chrome Extension: Is it possible to check an element's position on page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I am working on an extension that does Text Analysis. The extension will first fetch the content of the page, it will then check if the certain link is found, it will check whether it is on top of the page, middle or bottom. I found a link related to [viewport](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/) but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Use getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @wOxxOm So you are suggesting what was mentioned in the article, that it is on ViewPort or not?

Comment: Assuming you already tried it, I don't understand what's wrong about it and what is a ViewPort. If you mean a viewport as a visible part of the page, then yes the position is relative to that.

Comment: @wOxxOm No I have not tried it, I just found the article but I was not sure it tells whether the certain element is found below or top of the page.